# Aplicar fuente en un SVG de un Componente React

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, next.js, fuentes

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con un svg y es que quiero aplicar una fuente a las letras, como se espera funciona bien si tengo la fuente instalada en el PC obviamente, pero quiero agregar dicha fuente es al proyecto para que funcione donde sea.

Es un proyecto en Next.js y el svg está ubicado en `public/images/logo.js` mientras que la fuente está en `public/fonts/Oceanwide.otf`

***Archivo logo.svg***

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
   st1: {
      fontFamily: 'Oceanwide'////Si tuviera la fuente instalada en el PC asi funcionaria perfecto
   },
  //Demas estilos: colores, margin, fontsize...
});

const PPacLogoHorizontal = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <svg
        version="1.1"
        id="Capa_1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"
        style={{ enableBackground: 'new 0 0 1366 768' }}
        xmlSpace="preserve"
        width="16rem"
        className={`${classes.st10}`}
      >
        <text transform="matrix(1.0592 0 0 1 600.7451 585.6221)">
          <tspan x="0" y="0" className={`${classes.st0} ${classes.st1} ${classes.st2}`}>
            test
          </tspan>
          <tspan x="704.1" y="0" className={`${classes.st3} ${classes.st1} ${classes.st2}`}>
            test{' '}
          </tspan>
          <tspan x="100" y="121.3" className={`${classes.st4} ${classes.st5} ${classes.st6}`}>
            test
          </tspan>
        </text>
        <rect x="1385.4" y="517.4" className={`${classes.st7}`} width="305.6" height="20.5" />
        <g>
          <linearGradient
            id="SVGID_1_"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x1="473.4053"
            y1="330.5422"
            x2="233.5917"
            y2="531.7698"
            gradientTransform="matrix(0.7354 -3.462108e-02 3.686701e-02 0.7186 125.3408 237.328)"
          >
            <stop offset="0.1851" style={{ stopColor: '#28B5E0' }} />
            <stop offset="0.3107" style={{ stopColor: '#21A8D9' }} />
            <stop offset="0.8872" style={{ stopColor: '#0071B9' }} />
          </linearGradient>
          <path
            className={`${classes.st8}`}
            d="M416.4,399c23.8,2.4,38.3,15.6,52.2,29.9c20.4,21.1,41.5,41.6,62.2,62.5c24.1,24.2,22.2,61.8-4.1,84
        c-10.6,9-20.9,18.2-31.8,27c-8.4,6.8-26.2,7.6-35.8-2.9c-4.1-4.5-7.7-7.4-10.6-11.7c-5.5-8.1-8.1-16.8-1.4-24.1
        c9.3-10.2,22.6-25,24.7-38.9c4.9-23.5-9.3-40.6-28.9-53.5c-17.7-11.6-37.6-12.9-56.8-3.4c-18.1,8.9-33,21.9-47.2,35.2
        c-13.5,12.6-7.8,23.7,8.9,39.3c24.1,22.7,48.2,47.9,72.3,73.2c3.9,4.1,8.2,8.2,11.7,12.7c8.3,10.7,4.7,21.9-9.1,25.9
        c-20.6,6-40.7,2.5-56.4-10.4c-29.8-24.6-56.4-52.4-81.9-80.7c-21.8-24.3-19.2-60.1,5.8-81.5c25-21.4,50.3-42.5,75.3-63.8
        c8.4-7.2,18.5-12.3,28-16C398.4,400.8,398,398,416.4,399z"
          />

          <linearGradient
            id="SVGID_2_"
            gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x1="334.3986"
            y1="425.3888"
            x2="407.3951"
            y2="390.1589"
            gradientTransform="matrix(0.7354 -3.462108e-02 3.686701e-02 0.7186 125.3408 237.328)"
          >
            <stop offset="2.475700e-02" style={{ stopColor: '#0071B9' }} />
            <stop offset="0.232" style={{ stopColor: '#1188CA' }} />
            <stop offset="0.4577" style={{ stopColor: '#1E9AD6' }} />
            <stop offset="0.6989" style={{ stopColor: '#26A5DE' }} />
            <stop offset="0.9804" style={{ stopColor: '#28A8E0' }} />
          </linearGradient>
          <path
            className={`${classes.st9}`}
            d="M417.2,495.5c10,1.6,14.2,6.4,17,12.8c3.1,7.1,3.3,11.1-3.9,18.2c-20.1,16.1-23.6,24.4-40.5,5.3
        c-1.7-1.9-10.4-9.1-8.1-13.3C385.1,512.1,405.5,494.8,417.2,495.5z"
          />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </>
  );
};
```

Cualquier otra petición quedo atento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUCION:***

Modificación en el archivo `next.config.js` para la configuración del entorno de desarrollo y construcción, el código personaliza la configuración de **Next.js** para permitir la carga de archivos fuentes en el lado del cliente.

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Configuración para cargar fuentes en el lado del cliente
    if (!isServer) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8192,
            publicPath: '/_next/static/fonts/',
            outputPath: 'static/fonts/',
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            esModule: false
          }
        }
      });
    }
    return config;
  }
};
```

***CSS:***

Creación de un nuevo archivo css en **src/components/styles/fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Oceanwide';
  src: url('/fonts/Oceanwide.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

***Ubicación de la fuente:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Importación de CSS en _app.js***

```
import '/src/styles/fonts.css';
```